# SQL query with pivot gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ClientNumber, ClientName, YearEndDate, schedule, a1, ad1, a2, ad2, a3, ad3,
cv.[id] as CvId, 
[dataCV] = 
CASE cv.[id]
WHEN 'DATUM_AVA' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, cv.[data], 112)
WHEN 'RECHTSVORM' THEN cv.[data]
END,
DATEADD(day, 30, [data]) AS Stat_Filing_Date,
To_Be_Filed = 
CASE 
WHEN DATEADD(day, 30, [data]) < GETDATE() THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END
FROM EngagementFiles ef 
INNER JOIN ac
ON ef.id = ac.EngagementFile_Id
INNER JOIN cv
ON ef.id = cv.EngagementFile_Id
RIGHT JOIN sh
ON ac.short_name = sh.a3 OR ac.short_name = sh.a2 OR ac.short_name = sh.a1
WHERE (schedule = 'G21-9A' OR schedule = 'G21-9B') AND sh.EngagementFile_Id = ef.id AND (ac.act_type = 'C' OR ac.act_type = 'H')
AND schedule =
CASE WHEN
    (
    SELECT cv.[data]
    FROM cv
    WHERE [id] = 'REPORT_TYPE' AND cv.EngagementFile_Id = ef.id
    ) LIKE '%VKT%' THEN 'G21-9B' ELSE 'G21-9A' END
AND ((cv.[id] = 'DATUM_AVA' AND cv.[form] = '' AND cv.[group] = ''))
) AS s
PIVOT (
    MAX(dataCV)
    FOR [CvId] IN ([DATUM_AVA]
    )
)AS pvt
```

This returns the following result:

[image]

Now I want to add another column in the pivot part which also comes from the cv table. The structure of this table is kind of weird. It has the following columns:id, form, group and data.

The columns id, form and group are actually some kind of unique id which is used in a different application.

The column i want to add contains the data from the cv table where id = RECHTSVORM and group and form are empty.

The query with which I tried this is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ClientNumber, ClientName, YearEndDate, schedule, a1, ad1, a2, ad2, a3, ad3,
cv.[id] as CvId, 
[dataCV] = 
CASE cv.[id]
WHEN 'DATUM_AVA' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, cv.[data], 112)
WHEN 'RECHTSVORM' THEN cv.[data]
END,
DATEADD(day, 30, [data]) AS Stat_Filing_Date,
To_Be_Filed = 
CASE 
WHEN DATEADD(day, 30, [data]) < GETDATE() THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END
FROM EngagementFiles ef 
INNER JOIN ac
ON ef.id = ac.EngagementFile_Id
INNER JOIN cv
ON ef.id = cv.EngagementFile_Id
RIGHT JOIN sh
ON ac.short_name = sh.a3 OR ac.short_name = sh.a2 OR ac.short_name = sh.a1
WHERE (schedule = 'G21-9A' OR schedule = 'G21-9B') AND sh.EngagementFile_Id = ef.id AND (ac.act_type = 'C' OR ac.act_type = 'H')
AND schedule =
CASE WHEN
    (
    SELECT cv.[data]
    FROM cv
    WHERE [id] = 'REPORT_TYPE' AND cv.EngagementFile_Id = ef.id
    ) LIKE '%VKT%' THEN 'G21-9B' ELSE 'G21-9A' END
AND ((cv.[id] = 'DATUM_AVA' AND cv.[form] = '' AND cv.[group] = '')
OR (cv.[id] = 'RECHTSVORM' AND cv.[form] = '' AND cv.[group] = ''))
) AS s
PIVOT (
    MAX(dataCV)
    FOR [CvId] IN ([DATUM_AVA],
                    [RECHTSVORM]
    )
)AS pvt
```

But this gives the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I'm guessing this is because for the RECHTSVORM column it is also trying to convert cv.data to a datetime.
What do I need to change in order for the query to only convert cv.data to datetime for the DATUM_AVA column?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that one of the `Data` values in the `'DATUM_AVA'` rows is not in the correct format for a `112` style `DATETIME`. In this case `'yyyymmdd'`. See [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) in the MSDN.  You can check by selecting from the `cv` table with the same predicates and checking the values.

Irrespective of the above the column you are creating, `dataCV`, cannot be more than one data type. You are potentially trying to insert a `DATETIME` value and values with the originating column data type in to the created `dataCV` column. If you need to know that it is a `DATETIME` value, add an additional column to the pivot to help you identify the potential data type. You can then convert afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean add an additional column to the pivot?
What would that query look like?